# Can any U.S. government agency fund any think-tank?

Tags: united-states, government

> **Top think tank funders from within the U.S. government include the
> Office of the Secretary of Defense, the Air Force, the Army, the
> Department of Homeland Security, and the State Department.** The defense
> contractors that forked over the most to think tanks were Northrop
> Grumman, Raytheon, Boeing, Lockheed Martin and Airbus.

https://www.theamericanconservative.com/swamp-report-top-50-u-s-think-tanks-receive-over-1b-from-gov-defense-contractors/

Can any U.S. government agency fund any think-tank?

I was surprised that the Office of the Secretary of Defense, the Air Force, the Army, the Department of Homeland Security, and the State Department can all independently decide to fund a think-tank like the RAND corporation. I thought that it was the Federal government alone who would do it instead of several government agencies doing it on their own. Can any U.S. government agency fund any think-tank, or is it limited to some important ones?

Comment: Would a US federal agency be scrutinized if it hired a private company that had expertise in a given field but wasn't called a think-tank? Should the label attached to that company (think-tank vs. consulting firm vs. subject matter expert) affect the status of the contract?

Comment: "I thought that it was the Federal government alone who would do it instead of several government agencies doing it on their own." Federal agencies *are* the federal government. When "the federal government" does something, that means a federal agency is doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The agencies you list are all parts of the Federal government. The main restrictions on what agencies can spend money on are that it be legal, and that they can defend the spending to Congress as part of the agency's purpose.

Since the agencies have quite broad purposes, and think-tanks come and go pretty frequently, trying to restrict which tanks an agency can commission to do studies sounds like a fine way to waste a lot of legislative time. It is necessary to give agencies some freedom in their operations. Not doing that would risk the government being unable to plan ahead for circumstances which can only be vaguely foreseen.